# Change of basis such that the line $\ell=\{tx:t\in\mathbf{R}\}$ passes through the origin and $(1,0,\ldots,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V=n$, and let $x$ be a vector in $V$. Let $\ell=\{tx:t\in\mathbf{R}\}$. Denote $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Assuming that the representation of the line $\ell$ is given with respect to the standard basis, I would like to find a change of basis from the standard basis $B$ to $B'$ such that $[x]_{B'}=(1,0,\ldots,0)$, i.e. the line $\ell$ is rotated such that it passes through the origin when $t=0$ and the unit vector $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ when $t=1$. I need help finding a new basis $B'$ that satisfies this condition.

*My thoughts so far:* The new basis $B'$ must contain the vector $x$; since any vector can be built as a unique linear combination of the basis vectors, we would then have:
$$[x]_{B'}=a_1x+\cdots=(1,0,\ldots,0)\implies a_1=1,a_i=0\,\forall i>1$$
Now the trouble is just finding $n-1$ other basis vectors all linearly independent from $x$, and I am not entirely sure how to go about this.

I am fairly new to linear algebra so my experience in this field is limited. Any hints on how to go about finding a suitable new basis $B'$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for an explicit basis or to show the existence of one?

Comment: @copper.hat either would be helpful in the context of how I am using this. Preferably an explicit basis, but if you have a proof that such a change of basis exists that would be good too.

Comment: Any collection of linearly independent vectors that do not span the whole space can be extended to span the whole space.

Comment: @copper.hat so given that the vector $x$ is in the basis $B'$, we know that there exist $n-1$ other vectors that, together with $x$, form a basis for $V$?

Comment: Well, given any $x \neq 0$, there are $n-1$ vectors that together with $x$ form a basis. The basis $B'$ is irrelevant for this statement.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand now, thank you! If you would like to post this as an answer I will accept it.